# Animating a Custom Bezier Curve based on Progress of certain event

Tags: css, uibezierpath, bezier

How can we animate a closed parabolic bezier curve based on the progress of a certain event?

More Context ::

1. Platform: HTML5 Canvas
2. Curve constructed with the help of 2 parabolas intersecting each other ( When the progress is 100% )
3. But when the progress is let's say 10%, how we can create a bezier curve for this situation?

PS: There are other SO questions which show how to build a circular progress bar but what I'm looking at is a parabolic progress bar.

Comment: This is a _pretty_ vague question: remember that SO [is not about](/help/on-topic) asking people for tutorials, or programming resources, etc. so unless you can rephrase this as a concrete programming question, there's not much here for SO (even if it's a good question for some other, general programming help forum)

Comment: Of course, let me rephrase it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You're probably going to want to still show some actual code, and explain what you already looked at. Both JS and SMIL are not exactly hard to find _tons_ of tutorials about when you search for animated SVG, and animations in the canvas is literally what it exists for, so that's got tons of tutorials too. Try to fit your post to the standard process: 1. what did you set out to do, 2. what did you find that allowed you to move forward, 3. what code did you write (show that code, in [mcve] form!), 4. what is it doing wrong, and 5. what did you _already try_ to address that?

Comment: (because again, remember: SO is not for "how do I X", it's for "I did X, I expected Y, it did Z, I have no idea why even after trying A, B, and C to fix it, which I found by searching the web/stackoverflow")

Comment: Awesome thanks for the wonderful SO primer @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Much appreciated. I'll update my question as per the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake filling any SVG curve in canvas with a bit of a mix of SVG and Canvas to calculate some things:

```js
const path = document.querySelector( '#computing-path' );
const canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );
const progress = document.querySelector( '#progress' );
const bezierPoints = [
  [50, 50],
  [0, 30],
  [20, 180],
  [180, 150]
];
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

/* We need to set the SVG path to compute its length */
path.setAttribute( 'd', `M${bezierPoints[0].join()} C ${bezierPoints[1].join()} ${bezierPoints[2].join()} ${bezierPoints[3].join()}` );

const pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
    
/* `p` will be a normalised value between 0 and 1 */
function draw( p = 0 ){
    
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    
    if( p <= 0 ) return;
    
    ctx.save();
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    
    /** This is the crucial bit - the second value is very large because we want the empty space of the dash to stretch to at least the end. */
    ctx.setLineDash([ p * pathLength, pathLength * 10 ]);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( ...bezierPoints[0] );
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(
      ...bezierPoints[1],
      ...bezierPoints[2],
      ...bezierPoints[3]
    );
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  
}

draw( progress.value );

progress.addEventListener( 'input', event => draw( progress.value ));
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background: gray; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; gap: 20px;  }
canvas { border: 1px solid white; }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="visibility:hidden;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;transform:translate(-100%,-100%)"><path id="computing-path" /></svg>
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<input id="progress" type="range" min="0" max="1" value=".5" step=".01" />
```

Comment: Amazing answer @somethinghere, much appreciated !!